# Export multiple Excel Chart into one PDF with C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, pdf

How can I export multiple Excel Charts into one PDF File? In Excel I would select each Chart Tab with the mouse and then save  via "save as" PDF.

In C# I tried to loop over every Chart and use the methode select().

If I then use the ExportAsFixedFormat function, all charts, worksheets are saved in one PDF. But I only want the charts.

```
List<string> chartnames = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < workbook.Charts.Count; i++)
{
   chartnames.Add(workbook.Charts[i + 1].Name);
}
workbook.Charts[chartnames.ToArray()].select();
workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, filename);
```

Comment: Your post is unclear. Consider adding images to your post that illustrate what you're describing. Also provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows what you've already tried.

Comment: I added a code example

Comment: You don't *export* anything to PDF. You print it. PDF is a set of print instructions. `ExportAsFixedFormat` *prints* the contents of a Workbook as PDF and saves it to the file you specify. To control what gets printed you have to use print layout features, the same way you would if you wanted to print to paper. You *may* be able to use print areas to control what gets printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works. ExportAsFixedFormat only saves the visible worksheets

```
List<string> chartnames = new List<string>();
    
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.Charts.Count; i++)
{
  chartnames.Add(workbook.Charts[i + 1].Name);
}
    
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.Worksheets.Count; i++)
{
  workbook.Worksheets[i + 1].Visible = false;
}
    
workbook.Charts[chartnames.ToArray()].select();
workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, filename);
    
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.Worksheets.Count; i++)
{
  workbook.Worksheets[i + 1].Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what's going on. You're *hiding* all worksheets before "printing" the selected objects. That's unusual to say the least

Comment: ExportAsFixedFormat only saves the visible worksheets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).